# Ошибка при создании bundle в Symfony 3

Tags: php, composer, symfony3

Создаю bundle в Symfony 3 через консоль:

1. php console generate:bundle --namespace=Myvendor
2. Bundle name: MyvendorBlogBundle
3. Все пункты проходят проверку кроме одного:

> Checking that the bundle is autoloaded: FAILED
>
> The command was not able to configure everything automatically.
> You'll need to make the following changes manually.
>
> Edit the composer.json file and register the bundle namespace in the
> "autoload" section:

Comment: `Edit the composer.json file and register the bundle namespace in the "autoload" section: ` так всё же написано в composer.json надо вписать в секцию autoload namespace руками

Comment: Да это понятно, но почему FAILED? Почему в composer.json не произошли изменения?

Comment: права доступа скорее всего `ls -l composer.json`

Comment: Забыл упомянуть, используется Windows 8.1

Comment: Я незнаю как в Windows проверить скорее всего правой кнопкой права файла и т.д. и т.п.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему вы указываете namespace при создании бандла? Конечно failed, потому что вам нужно будет настроить autoload для поиска файлов для переданного вами namespace'а. Не указывайте namespace и все будет хорошо, а если вам реально нужен отдельный namespace отдельный от всего проекта, тогда не поленитесь и настройте под него секцию autoload в composer.json

Answer (score 0):

версия symfony 3.3.4 php 7.0
Необходимо отредактировать в файле composer.json раздел autoload к виду:

"psr-4": { "": "src/" },

А потом выполнить composer dump-autoload